# Object of class 'modelName' could not be converted to int in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, explode, implode

I am trying to create an invoice number like - `HCL/LF/02/2018` in where the number will be incremented by one for the new invoice. Would someone help me please to get expected `invoice_no`? I tried something like this in my controller -

```
public function create()
{
    $check = OrderProformaInvoice::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    $number = 01;
    $year   = date('Y');
    if (count($check) > 0) {

        $invoiceNo = OrderProformaInvoice::latest()->first(['invoice_no']);

        $arr     = array('HCL','LF', $invoiceNo + 1, $year);
        $newInvoiceNo = implode("/",$arr);
    }else{

        $arr     = array('HCL','LF', $number, $year);
        $newInvoiceNo = implode("/",$arr);

    }
    return view('admin.marchendaising.order-proforma-invoices.create', compact('newInvoiceNo'));
}
```

And in my view form input field is-

```
<input type="text" name="invoice_no" class="form-control" value="{{ $newInvoiceNo }}">
```

Comment: What do you get when run this code? Also for the invoice number, since you've already made a DB call to get all of your invoices your `$invoiceNo` could just be `count($check) + 1`. Under year you could write `$numOfInvoices = count(check)` then just call `$numOfInvoices++`. 

Edit: I've just noticed you're not even saving the new invoice in the create function, so the number is never going to increment unless you're saving them?

Comment: Could You dump `$invoiceNo` ? Is it object or int?

Comment: For my previous entry, I manually inserted in `invoice_no` field `HCL/LF/01/2018`

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in this line:

```
$invoiceNo = OrderProformaInvoice::latest()->first(['invoice_no']);
```

Correct:

```
$invoiceNo = OrderProformaInvoice::latest()->get()->invoice_no;
```

Comment: Now I am getting - `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$invoice_no` error.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake here:

`$invoiceNo = OrderProformaInvoice::latest()->first(['invoice_no']);`

There was no need for this line since you already have a count of all of the `OrderProformaInvoice` so we may aswell set this to a variable and just increase it for a new one rather than making another call to the database.

If you ever were to delete a database record, you could use

`$invoice = OrderProfromaInvoice::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();`

Then instead of `$numOfInvoices++` you could do `$invoice->id++` which will take the ID of the latest invoice and increment it by one.

```
public function create()
{
    $check = OrderProformaInvoice::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    $year   = date('Y');
    $numOfInvoices = count($check)

    $arr = array('HCL','LF', $numOfInvoices++, $year);
    $newInvoiceNo = implode("/",$arr);


    // You could also just do this

    $newInvoiceNo = 'HCL/LF/' . $numOfInvoices++ . '/' . $year;
    // $newInvoiceNo will equal example: 'HCL/LF/12/2018';


    return view('admin.marchendaising.order-proforma-invoices.create', compact('newInvoiceNo'));
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It doesn't say you're getting an error in your question.

Comment: If you're still getting ModelName could not be converted to int, that would be from this line here: `$arr     = array('HCL','LF', $invoiceNo + 1, $year);` Where $invoiceNo I assume would be your model, `dd($invoiceNo)` or `var_dump($invoiceNo)` and tell us what that gives you.

Comment: I've updated my answer, removing the if statement as it would be pointless if you just take the $numOfInvoices and adding one every time. You could also do use `DB::table('invoice_table')->count();` which will return an int. Then there would be no need for the `count($check)`. You can learn about it [here by scrolling down to aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results)